# Draggable text in html / javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to make a paragraph movable. I have tried to search the web but i can't find  anything. So is it possible?

I tried this but i can't move it:

```
<p draggable="true">This is a test</p>
```

[I get this.](http://adrinet.tk/test)

Comment: take a look at this: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if i used  [This as Mikey posted in a comment.](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Now it works like a charm.

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out :)...There is a lot more cool stuff around there. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the

```
draggable="true"
```

for your paragraph. [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zLYGF/30/)

Check [MDN for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations).

Comment: Am I missing something? This is not an answer and it also does not work. Btw, mootools? OP does not even mention that.

Comment: @Mikey:- OP has edited the question after I have answered and secondly the link which I have provided ie., of MDN is useful and I guess that should help OP if he will go through it and put some effort.